# Microsoft Translator Hub Portal does not seem to work properly

Tags: microsoft-translator

I am not sure how to review the Evaluation results from Microsoft Translator Hub. The portal does not seem to do anything apart from displaying the evaluation results. I have assigned myself as a reviewer still it does not let me provide any feedback into model.

Adding/removing a reviewer does not seem to work properly. I am able to select the check box time corresponding to reviewer in the Assign reviewer screen once. After that it is disabled.

The members table is empty, it does not display the list of member who are part of a project. And if I try to add a member it seems to send invitation but does not display under the members tab.

I have used Excel to input the translations with source and target texts in each column. It had 30000 rows of translation. Text lengths range from 1 to 10 words.

Any help on this is highly appreciated,

Thanks,
Sarath

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to select the users who have accepted the invitation and logged into the portal once to be able to add them as reviewers for a specific translation.

If you have added them as members for the project, but the reviewers have not yet accepted the invitation, they will not be shown in this list.

The checkbox for assigning a reviewer is disabled because the reviewer has already been added. We will fix the UI issue where the checkbox for an already added user is disabled but it does not show up as having been added.